# Optional grouping in Scala Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, scala

Say I want to make a regex that splits a optional version number from a file name i.e

```
val regex(name, ver) = "file.jar"          // name = file, ver = empty
val regex(name, ver) = "some-software.jar" // name = some-software, ver = empty
val regex(name, ver) = "software-1.0.jar"  // name = software, ver = 1.0
val regex(name, ver) = "some-file-1.0.jar" // name = some-file, ver = 1.0
```

How is such a regular expression written in Scala/Java ?. In perl I would do something along the lines of:

> (.*)(-(\d|.)*)?.jar

but Scala does not seam to support making optional groups in this syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what your question now is.

I assume it is not matching the second group, because the first one is greedy and since the second is optional, the first matches everything.

Try this:

```
(.*?)(?:-(?=\d)(.*))?.jar
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v8m4)

1. I made the first group a lazy match with the `.*?`
2. The second group is a non capturing group (the one starting with `(?:`. You will find the name now in group 1 and the version in group 2.
3. I put a lookahead after the dash, so that it searches for a dash followed by a digit.

Comment: Great thanks it works, I will try to reformulate my question so it make more sense

Comment: Thanks for the extended explanation.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
/^(.+?)(?:-([\d.]*))?\.jar$/
```

Assuming version is always a mixed of digits and dots.